# Using fb_graph to post to Facebook fan page from Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook

I hear that fb_graph is the way to go and I already have my app registered with Facebook but I don't know how to get the access token to post things. I have my app ID and secret but I need to get that access token. All I'm trying to do is post to a Facebook fan page (as the page).

How do I get the access token?

Comment: did you found out how to get the access token? cheers

Answer (score 4):

Get the user:

```
user = FbGraph::User.me(access_token)
user.fetch
```

To see the users accounts details:

```
user.accounts
```

Select the Facebook page that you want to post to:

```
account = user.accounts.select {|account| account if account.name == "*Your Page Name*"}.first

(account.access_token => the pages access token) 
(account.identifier => page id)
```

Create new page instance:

```
page = FbGraph::Page.new(account.identifier)
```

Post to the page:

```
note = page.note!(:access_token => account.access_token, :subject => "Hello World", :message => "hey, this is a test from rails")
```

Comment: After a user logs into your app facebook returns the access_token to your site.

Answer (score 1):

The step-by-step procedure for access token with **Oauth 2.0** is found here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/. If you require a sample code in Ruby, create a new app and under "**Hosting URL**", click on "**get one**" and select **Ruby** programming language when prompted. It also contains code to pull from Graph API.

Answer (score 1):

I highly highly recommend the new gem [Koala](https://github.com/arsduo/koala) for working with facebook.

Answer (score 0):

If you do a call to  https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts

and pass in your access_token it will return data listing all the pages you have access to and the access_tokens needed to post to those walls.#

You get your access token by logging in and the access token is passed back by the login process.